# Android - How to share data(for example json) through an app link that you can send to other people(through for example e-mail or whatsapp)?

Tags: android

Lets say i create an app, and that app has x steps. a step is a set of instructions and x images( like a how-to app)

My idea was to send the instructions and and convert the image to binary, and put them into a json.

What i am looking for, is a way to create a link, or send the json to someone over e-mail or whatsapp, and then when they click this link, my app will open and read the json.

Is there any of doing this in android ? I've looked at android app links and googled some more but couldn't come to a solution

Comment: Since a image is a heavy object serialize it will be cost on data, why don't you add the values to the server and send a link to the server data?

Comment: I don't have a server, i'm just trying to create one "file" that the user can import and get everything

Comment: Look for schema metadata on Android. Generate the JSON file and download it on the second side and create a URL like yourapp://path-to-json and load it

Comment: What would path-to-json be? Then id have to upload it somewhere, right?

Comment: The one where the other user downloaded your json